# Изменение css динамически. Непонятный косяк

Tags: javascript, jquery

При переключении языка вверху страницы, права - css на миллисекунду пропадает и это очень заметно.

Делал изменение так:
В head прописал:

```html
<link id="CSSsource" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

А потом в js вот так подкидывал новый при смене языка:

```js
$('.rus').on('click', function() {
      var r = $('.localization').each(function() {
      var el = $(this);
      var key = (el.attr('caption'));
        el.html(rus[key]);
        new_link.href = "css/style.css"; //изменение css
      });
  });

  $('.eng').on('click', function() {
      var r = $('.localization').each(function() {
      var el = $(this);
      var key = (el.attr('caption'));
          el.html(eng[key]);
          new_link.href = "css/style_en.css"; //изменение css
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Вот линк на тестовый сайт: [введите сюда описание ссылки](http://sarpedon.v4.dtraduga.vh55.hosterby.com/)

Comment: $("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/css/style_en.css' />");

Comment: Только вот проблемка другая нарисовалась. Вот что в коде творится при переключении после первого клика: https://prnt.sc/l7060p

Comment: может можно как-то сделать чтобы добавлялось 1 раз а предыдущее удалялось и нааборот при смене языка?

Comment: Ответил ответом ниже, посмотрите то ли это что вам нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Тогда можно сделать вот так:

```js
$("#ru").click(function(){ 
  if ( $('link[href="/css/style_en.css"]').length > 0  ) {   
    $('link[href="/css/style_en.css"]').remove();
    $("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/css/style.css' />");
  }
});

$("#eng").click(function(){
  if ( $('link[href="/css/style.css"]').length > 0  ) {  
    $('link[href="/css/style.css"]').remove();
    $("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/css/style_en.css' />");
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
 <link id="CSSsource" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</head>
   <body>   
      <button id="ru">Ru</button>    
      <button id="eng">Eng</button> 
   </body>
</html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Результат:**

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Update 0.0.2

HTML

```
<div class="change_language">
    <a class="rus" href="?lang=rus" type="button">rus</a>
    <a class="eng" href="?lang=eng" type="button">eng</a>
</div>
```

---

JS

```
var lang = document.location.search.split("=")[1];

if (lang == "rus") {
    $("head").append('<link priority="async" rel="preload" href="/css/style.css" as="style" onload="this.rel=\'stylesheet\'">');
}else if (lang == "eng"){
    $("head").append('<link  priority="async" rel="preload" href="/css/style_en.css" as="style" onload="this.rel=\'stylesheet\'">');
}
```

Comment: Странно почему-то но у меня самый первый вариант перестал работать - тоже опять с мельканием.
А в последнем это я так понимаю все на одну кнопку вешается? А можно ли это как-то на 2 раскинуть?

Comment: попробовал вариант что вы поправили выше для двух кнопок, но у него вообще никакой реакции

Comment: Я запускаю: http://prntscr.com/l72j4q
Появляются 2 кнопки но при клике пути к css не меняются

Comment: видимо я плуг((( сейчас попробую разобраться

Comment: все меняется, как у вас на гифке, но мелькание осталось так как и в первом варианте :(((
 (я правил в одном месте а проверял в другом - вот и не работало)

Comment: пообщался еще с людьми, сказали что скорее всего не получится должного эффекта добиться - нужно делать перезагрузку страницы просто уже с другим css - но я такого еще ни разу не делал ((

Comment: перезагрузка это: location.reload();
но можно ли как-то это приобщить в ваш код, чтобы произошла перезагрузка после клика по нужному языку и применялся нужный css?

Comment: можете подсказать в реализации? я пока еще только учусь. Логику понимаю, а как правильно описать кодом - пока еще не хватает опыта.

Comment: @predel2007 Обновил ответ